# How do I split a string without deleting delimiters?

Tags: string, split, autoit

My AutoIt script parses text by sentences. Because they most likely end in a period, question mark or exclamation point, I used this to split text by sentence:

```
$LineArray = StringSplit($displayed_file, "!?.", 2)
```

The problem; it deletes delimiters (periods, question marks, and exclamation points at the end of sentences). For example, the string `One. Two. Three.` is split into `One`, `Two`, and `Three`.

How can I split into sentences while retaining the periods, question marks, and exclamation points that end these sentences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`StringSplit()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/StringSplit.htm) the delimiters are consumed in the process (and so are lost for the result). Using [`StringRegExp()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/StringRegExp.htm) :

```
#include <array.au3>
$string="This is a text. It has several sentences. Really? Of Course!"
$a = stringregexp($string,"(?U)(.*[.?!])",3)
_ArrayDisplay($a)
```

To remove leading space(s), change the pattern to `"(?U)[ ]*?(.*[.?!])"`. Or to `"(?U) *?(.*[.?!] )"` to split at `[.!?]` plus `<space>` (adding a space to the last sentence):

```
#include <array.au3>
$string = "Do you know Pi?   Yes!   What's it?    It's 3.14159!   That's correct."
$a = StringRegExp($string & " ", "(?U)[ ]*?(.*[.?!] )", 3)
_ArrayDisplay($a)
```

To preserve `@CRLF` (`\r\n`) inside sentences:

```
#include <array.au3>
$string = "Do you " & @CRLF & "know Pi?   Yes!  What's it?    It's" & @CRLF & "3.14159!   That's correct."
$a = StringRegExp($string & "  ", "(?s)(?U)[ ]*?(.*[.?!][ \R] )", 3)
_ArrayDisplay($a,"Sentences")   ;_ArrayDisplay doesn't show @CRLF

For $i In $a
    ;MsgBox(0,"",$i)
    ConsoleWrite(StringStripWS($i, 3) & @CRLF & "---------" & @CRLF)
Next
```

This does not keep `@CRLF` when end of line is same as end of sentence: `...line end!" & @CRLF & "Next line...`.

Comment: Your line of code does exactly what I wanted it to do.  I have one question.  How can I edit it to retain @CRLF?  It retains spaces between sentences just fine, but it does not retain newline characters.  I would really appreciate it if you could give me an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include<Array.au3>
Global $str = "One. Two. Three. This is a test! Does it work? Yes, man! "
$re = StringRegExp($str, '(.*?[.!?])', 3)
_ArrayDisplay($re)
```

This pattern works without the space at the beginning of a sentence

```
#include<Array.au3>
Global $str = "One. Two. Three.This is a test! Does it work? Yes, man! "
$re = StringRegExp($str, '(\S.*?[.!?])', 3)
_ArrayDisplay($re)
```